# I want to delete a row from DB using web API with jQuery but row does not get deleted. My call does not reach to delete function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-sql

jQuery code:

```
  $('body').on('click', '.bt', function () {

        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        var id = '1';
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:52991/api/Values' + id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                  alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
        console.log($(this).parent().fadeOut(1000));
    });
```

Web Api function:

```
public string Delete(int id)
{
    if(rp.delete(id))
    {
    }

    return "done";
}
```

Delete code in delete repository:

```
public bool delete(int id)
{
     var row = dc.Users.First(a => a.Id == id);
     dc.Users.DeleteOnSubmit(row);
     dc.SubmitChanges();
     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
url: 'http://localhost:52991/api/Values' + id,
```

Need change to (add / after values)

```
url: 'http://localhost:52991/api/Values/' + id,
```